# $4$-manifold with fundamental group $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, low-dimensional-topology

Before I write my question, I want to write some thoughts.

Let $M$ be a connected topological manifold such that $\pi_1(M)=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. Then, considering its orientation $2$-fold cover, which is connected, I can say $M$ is orientable. Now, an example of such a closed $3$-manifold is $L(3,1)$.

Now, this type of argument can not be given if I consider $\pi_1(M)=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ to conclude $M$ is orientable. But Euler characteristic of an odd-dimensional closed manifold is always zero, so we cannot say $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is the fundamental group of any closed connected non-orientable $3$-manifold, as  $H_1(M,\Bbb Z)$ is infinite when $M$ is closed non-orientable connected $3$-manifold.

Again this logic can not be given for $4$-dimensional closed connected manifold. So, I am wondering if the following fact. I assume closed means compact without boundary.

> Does there exist closed connected $4$-manifolds both orientable and
> non-orientable type having fundamental group $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Every finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a compact $4$- dimensional manifold: take the standard 2-dimensional CW complex with that fundamental group, immerse it into $\Bbb R^4$ and take a regular neighborhood.

Comment: Does this argument gives both orientable and non-orientable, can you elaborate more. I will really appreciate if you write this as an answer.

Comment: @JCAA: that construction seems to me to produce either an open manifold or a manifold with boundary. I think you want to immerse into $\mathbb{R}^5$ and take the boundary of a tubular neighborhood, as Somnath Basu does here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/15421/290 (I don't know whether the result is orientable or not though.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A non-orientable example: consider the automorphism $f : S^2 \times S^2$ given by $(x, y) \mapsto (y, -x)$ where $-$ denotes the antipode map. This map has order $4$ and gives a free action of $\mathbb{Z}/4$ on $S^2 \times S^2$, so its quotient is a closed $4$-manifold $X$ with $\pi_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/4$. Since $\chi(S^2 \times S^2) = 4$ we have $\chi(X) = 1$ so $X$ is non-orientable; alternatively, we can check that $f$ acts by $-1$ on $H^4(S^2 \times S^2)$.

Comment: But, here we can not take orientation two-cover to get another orientable manifold. Am I right? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Math: why not? The orientation double cover is the quotient of $S^2 \times S^2$ by $f^2$, which sends $(x, y)$ to $(-x, -y)$. It turns out to be the real Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_2(\mathbb{R}^4)$.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that $\pi$ induced an index $2$-subgroup of $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ as covering induced map is injective.

Comment: What is going on with that Euler characteristic calculation? Is there some general theorem, if the group $G$ acts nicely on the space $Y$ then $\chi(Y)$ is related to $\chi(Y/G)$ by some relation?

Comment: @FShrike: yes. If a finite group $G$ acts freely on a reasonable space $Y$ (I don't know exactly what hypotheses are necessary here but finite CW complex should be fine e.g.) then $\chi(Y/G) = \frac{\chi(Y)}{|G|}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Damn. Is that easy to see? Likely yes, if there is some famous way of giving $Y/G$ a cell structure under reasonable conditions. Maybe if $Y/G$ is a CW complex there is a CW structure on $Y$ with $|G|$-many $n$-cells for each $n$-cell in $Y/G$. Just guessing

Comment: @FShrike: I think something like that can be made to work but I'm not familiar with the details, unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out, every finitely presented group arises as the fundamental group of a closed smooth orientable four-manifold.

The same is not true of non-orientable manifolds as $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ illustrates. A necessary condition is that the group must have an index two subgroup (i.e. the fundamental group of the orientable double cover). This turns out to be sufficient. That is, a finitely presented group is the fundamental group of a closed smooth non-orientable four-manifold if and only if it has an index two subgroup; see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/283794/21564).

Comment: My bad! I should  check this website before asking this question. Thanks. +1 for your help.